# How to call fetchxml query in MSCRM using Angularjs 2?

Tags: angularjs, dynamics-crm

I have a fetchxml query to get user detail from systemuser entity. How can I execute it in Angularjs 2.0?

Comment: I have added an answer but on reflection I presumed you were on the latest version of dynamics. Can you clarify in the question just so I can ensure my answer is indeed correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute FetchXML using the dynamics web api. The example on MSDN is account so I'm going to use that. Here's the sample fetchxml:

```
<fetch mapping='logical'> 
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='accountid'/> 
    <attribute name='name'/> 
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

URL encode the fetchxml and pass it in using the fetchXml parameter in a `GET` request like this:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=%3Cfetch%20mapping='logical'%3E%3Centity%20name='account'%3E%3Cattribute%20name='accountid'/%3E%3Cattribute%20name='name'/%3E%3C/entity%3E%3C/fetch%3E HTTP/1.1
```

Then just execute the `GET` request as you always would in angular. From a quick check it should be something like this:

```
this.http.get("[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=%3Cfetch%20mapping='logical'%3E%3Centity%20name='account'%3E%3Cattribute%20name='accountid'/%3E%3Cattribute%20name='name'/%3E%3C/entity%3E%3C/fetch%3E HTTP/1.1")
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

Where `extractData` and `handleError` are the relevant functions you want to handle those callbacks.

Taken from [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607533.aspx#Anchor_2) and [Angular 2 here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @SujathaNalashaa updated the question. After a downvote by someone (who should have really commented as to why they downvoted) I reread your question and spotted you were asking about Angular 2, not AngularJS.